# What event tells me when a browser goes into the background?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-browser

Eg when you switch to a different app on desktop or mobile, or just view the desktop / home screen. Neither `unload` nor `pagehide` fire in this situation. `visibilitychange` only fires when I switch tabs on desktop.

Comment: Desktop browsers will fire a `blur` event, I would hope mobile browsers do the same.

Comment: Thank you! `blur` event on `window` works on both desktop and ios safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript:
If you have an element in focus, the  `onblur()` event will fire.

jQuery:
If you have an element in focus, the  `focusout()` event will fire.

Comment: Answers should not require the use of a library that is not in the OP or tagged on the question.

Comment: Updated with pure JS answer.

Comment: what element is the event fired on when you background the browser? Is it `window, document, html, body`?